# How to query coordinates of companies from wikipedia using SPARQL?

Tags: rdf, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

Following is the query that I am executing at [SPARQL Endpoint](http://iwb.fluidops.com/search/?queryLanguage=SPARQL&queryTarget=default&infer=false&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fname%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Flocation%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproducts%20WHERE%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fname%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fclass%2Fyago%2FCompany108058098%3E.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fname%20%20dbpedia%3AlocationCity%20%3Flocation.%0D%0A%20%20%3Fname%20%20dbpedia%3Aproduct%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fproducts.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%20%0D%0A%20%20LIMIT%20%2020&repository=default):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?name  ?location  ?products WHERE{
    ?name  rdf:type   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098>.
    ?name  dbpedia:locationCity ?location.
    ?name  dbpedia:product          ?products.
} LIMIT  20
```

This query is executing as per my requirements but now I also want to get the coordinates (latitude/longtiude) for each of these companies. How should I construct the query to get coordinates for each of these companies?

Comment: Can you not just get latitude and longitude based on the location? As far as I can see, companies itself have no geographical data in Wikipedia resp. DBpedia.

Comment: You could try https://query.wikidata.org/ instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find our if they have this property I've used this request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE{
    ?name  rdf:type   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098>.
    ?name ?p ?o .
} LIMIT 2000
```

Then i was able to scroll down (on 2nd page) to check that they have lat and long property. I don't know prefix for them, so i've used full property name (decoded from url)

Here's request:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
?name ?lat ?long
WHERE{
    ?name  rdf:type   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098>.
    ?name  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat> ?lat.
    ?name  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?long.
} LIMIT 20
```

If you want that one with products:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
?name ?lat ?long
(GROUP_CONCAT(?product; separator = ",") as ?products)
WHERE{
    ?name  rdf:type   <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Company108058098>.
    ?name  dbpedia:product      ?product.
    ?name  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#lat> ?lat.
    ?name  <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#long> ?long.
} GROUP BY ?name ?lat ?long LIMIT 20
```